# Capistrano deploy unicorn ERROR uninitialized constant RAILS_ENV (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, capistrano, unicorn

I just successfully deployed my RoR app to AWS using Rubber & Capistrano.  However, when I navigate to the page it shows the default nginx page.  Clearly, I missed something during the setup phase to point nginx/unicorn to the right directory to serve my app.

[image: default nginx]

When I run `tail -f log/unicorn.stderr.log` I see the following:

```
E, [2015-12-07T14:23:41.253757 #3808] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 24405 exit 1> worker=0
E, [2015-12-07T14:23:41.301617 #24409] ERROR -- : uninitialized constant RAILS_ENV (NameError)
/ebs/microposts2-production/current/config/unicorn.rb:73:in `rescue in block in reload'
/ebs/microposts2-production/current/config/unicorn.rb:61:in `block in reload'
/ebs/microposts2-production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-5.0.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:611:in `call'
/ebs/microposts2-production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-5.0.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:611:in `init_worker_process'
/ebs/microposts2-production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-5.0.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:639:in `worker_loop'
/ebs/microposts2-production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-5.0.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:508:in `spawn_missing_workers'
/ebs/microposts2-production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-5.0.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:519:in `maintain_worker_count'
/ebs/microposts2-production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-5.0.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:283:in `join'
/ebs/microposts2-production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-5.0.1/bin/unicorn_rails:209:in `<top (required)>'
/ebs/microposts2-production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/unicorn_rails:23:in `load'
/ebs/microposts2-production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/unicorn_rails:23:in `<main>'
```

I assume since the environment was appended to my app name that `Rubber.env` existed, however this error makes me think otherwise.  Heck, I'm not even sure this issue even applies to the nginx default page issue.  Can someone please share what I've done wrong, or missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone looking, fixing unicorn template 5.0+ will work, refer:

> https://github.com/rubber/rubber/issues/570

Comment: Funny... I answered my own question somewhere else... lmfao

Answer (score 0):

You need to wipe out the default nginx virtualhost usually at `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`, just delete that file and then you should be good to go.

Comment: That directory doesn't exist.  I assume it's because i deployed with Rubber/Capistrano.  So, I see a `conf.d/` and `rubber/` folder with the respective `.conf` files in them.

Comment: What OS are you deploying on?

Comment: Run `nginx -t` to see the location where nginx is located, then check in the `sites-enabled` directory to see if there is anything in there. If there isn't anything or any symlinks to your apps shared config folder then you will need to set that up as well

Comment: not sure what I should be looking for `sudo nginx -t` yields: `nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful`

Comment: K now do `ls /etc/nginx/sites-enabled` and make sure there is output there other than default

Comment: Directory does not exist.  Care to move to a chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97231/discussion-between-cwitty-and-godzilla74).